# Set the div height same as fluid image height if (image position: fixed)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create responsive behavior with the fixed image on top and would like to achieve that the following content snapped to the bottom of the div that contains the image, but the image with position: fixed gives no height to the div, can you please point me what is wrong and if there is another way to achieve that?

```css
.slider {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 1100px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 350px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <img class='image' src='http://s2.postimg.org/vmnzo6e0p/top.jpg'>
</div>

<div class='content'>
</div>
```

Diagram of expierience that I would like to achieve.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a diagram of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody as you asked I've uploaded an image with some explanations.

Comment: If your image has a fixed ratio, you could use padding-top with a % value, it will change depending on the width of the div.
But I would rather do that through javascript, get the height of the image, and add that + a fixed constant. Make sure the run the script when the image is loaded (otherwise, it will return 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this using JQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/9hmyr40w/

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

.slider {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
}

.content {
    height: 1100px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
    var imageBottom = $(".image").height() - 15 
    $(".content").css("top",imageBottom)
})
```